# How do you inherit from a class in a different header file?

Tags: c++, inheritance, organization

I am having dependency troubles.  I have two classes: `Graphic` and `Image`.  Each one has its own .cpp and .h files.  I am declaring them as the following:

`Graphic.h`:

```
    #include "Image.h"
    class Image;
    class Graphic {
      ...
    };
```

`Image.h`:

```
    #include "Graphic.h"
    class Graphic;
    class Image : public Graphic {
      ...
    };
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
    Image.h:12: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

If I remove the forward declaration of `Graphic` from `Image.h` I get the following error:

```
    Image.h:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Graphic’
    Image.h:10: error: forward declaration of ‘struct Graphic’
```

Comment: As it stands right now, that should be working. What compiler are you using?

Are Image.h and Graphic.h both in the same folder on the filesystem?  Does your compiler know where to look for them?

Comment: Please don't edit the question so bad: it invalidates all these valuable answers.  Rather provide an answuer yourself, to keep the time-line intact.

Comment: I couldn't provide an answer as I did not know what the answer was - instead, I changed the question so it was more clear what I was trying to ask (the suggested changes did not help).

Comment: I fixed it by going through each relate source file and asking myself what includes and declarations were needed and what weren't, then deleting the ones that weren't.  Then it compiled fine.  Not sure what the problem was as I cannot reproduce the defect (it had to do with a separate file).

Comment: (rolled back to the first revision)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me:

Image.h:

```
#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H

#include "Graphic.h"
class Image : public Graphic {

};

#endif
```

Graphic.h:

```
#ifndef GRAPHIC_H
#define GRAPHIC_H

#include "Image.h"

class Graphic {
};

#endif
```

The following code compiles with no error:

```
#include "Graphic.h"

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to include Image.h or forward declare Image in Graphic.h - that's a circular dependency. If Graphic.h depends on anything in Image.h you need to split that out into a third header. (If Graphic has an Image member, that just isn't going to work.)

Comment: How does Graphic.h depend on Image.h?

Answer (score 4):

Graphic.h doesn't need to include image.h, and it doesn't need to forward declare the Image class.  Also, Image.h doesn't need to forward declare the Graphic class since you #include the file that defines that class (as you must).

`Graphic.h:`

```
class Graphic {
  ...
};
```

`Image.h`:

```
#include "Graphic.h"
class Image : public Graphic {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Image extends Graphic, remove the inclusion of Image in your Graphic.h file.

`Graphic.h`

```
class Graphic {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Also add header guards, then you have the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

First remove this, you must always have the complete class definition available in order to inherit from a class:

```
class Graphic;
```

Second, remove all references to Image from Graphic.h. The parent will usually not need to know of its childs.

Comment: I tried removing the forward declaration, as was stated in the question.